# JavaFX accessing stackpane within borderpane

Tags: javafx, fxml

The center of my BorderPane has a stackpane called designView (an FXML defined stackpane). I'm trying to get a draggable pane in the designView. If I add that pane to the rootView (my BordePane) all is well. If however I try to add it to the designView like this:

```
// This works fine except the pnae is on the wrong place obviously
....
Pane p = displayField.createDraggablePane(800.0, 800.0, 400.0, 300.0);
rootView.getChildren().add(p);


// Now the pane is in the right place, but it's 'stuck'
....
rootView.setCenter(designView);
Pane p = displayField.createDraggablePane(800.0, 800.0, 400.0, 300.0);
designView.getChildren().add(p);
```

The pane appears correctly in the designView, BUT it is no longer draggable. The MouseEvents fire, but the position of the pane is not updated. I think the problem is with the fact that layoutX, getSceneX, layoutXProperty etc. have no reference to designView, but how do I get that?  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of adding a StackPane to my BorderPane center, I have added a Pane and all is well :-) So my draggable Pane is added to a Pane instead of added to a StackPane.

Don't quite understand why this should change the behaviour of the draggable pane, but practice shows that it does.